# Use Visual Tools without installing Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I've a Windows Server 2012 for make my build every night. I want to use CMake to generate Makefiles with NMake. But I don't want to install a complete Visual Studio just to get the tools (compiler / linker).

I want to know if there is a way to do that or if I have to install visual imperative ?

I search on web but the answers i found are not so clear...

Thanks

Comment: Install just the Windows SDK in that case: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commmand line build Tools has been removed from the Windows SDK as of the "Windows SDK for Windows 8" release. Earlier SDKs included compilers. So if you use an SDK prior to the Windows 8 era you can go with the older SDKs.
If you new the current SDK version you need to install developer Tools like Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes. No tools and no compilers for Windows 8. :( thank you anyway